# Bash wildcard to match exactly n characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

Is there a wildcard in bash to match exactly 5 characters, shortening a pattern like `?????`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not yet.

With the `extglob` option, `bash` adds some of `ksh` extended globbing operators but not the `{x,y}(pattern)` one.

In `ksh93`, you use:

```
{5}(?)
```

With `zsh` with the `extendedglob` option:

```
?(#c5)
```

(you'll notice none of them are shorter than `?????` though).

In `bash`, you could do:

```
$(printf '%.0s?' {1..5})
```

though that's hardly an improvement and relies on `$IFS` not containing `?`.

Comment: Do any of these allow using a variable for 5?

Comment: @Random832, yes all but the 3rd one with `bash` (that one would also work with ksh93 or zsh in sh/ksh emulation though). With `bash`, you could use `$(seq "$n" | tr -cd '\n' | tr '\n' '?')` instead.

Comment: Or `$(yes '?' | tr -cd '?' | head -c $n)` - this is fun. Also, couldn't you remove the $IFS dependency by putting it in "quotes"?

Comment: @Random832, no. This time (and that's probably the only time you'll ever want to do that), you do want to use the `split+glob` operator (leaving an expansion unquoted) but only the `glob` part (you want that `?????` pattern to be expanded, which wouldn't happen if you quoted `$(...)`). Note that you use that `split+glob` operator with your unquoted `$n` which adds another requirement that `$IFS` must not contain digits. That one you can and should quote.